# Transitions is not working on my responsive navbar component

Tags: reactjs, sass, navbar, transition, styling

I have this navbar component, here is an image of it on a mobile view:
[image]
My question is, I cannot see a transition when clicking the hamburger menu to show the ul, I do not see it despite adding the transition on the ul itself, it just pops up immediately.

For reference, here is my Navbar.jsx

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import "../App.scss"
import { FaBars, FaTimes } from 'react-icons/fa';

const Navbar = () => {

const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
const toggleNav = () => {
    setIsOpen(!isOpen);
};
  return (
    <nav className="wrapper">
     <div className="navbar">
        <a href="/#" className="logo">LOGO</a>
        <div className= {`nav-links ${isOpen && "show"}`}>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="/#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="/#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="/#">Services</a></li>
                <li><a href="/#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div className="nav-toggle" onClick={toggleNav}>
                {isOpen ? <FaTimes /> : <FaBars />}
        </div>
     </div>
    </nav>
  )
}

export default Navbar
```

And here is my SCSS

```
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  list-style-type: none;
  text-decoration: none ;
}.wrapper{
  width: 100%;
  height: 90px;
  background: #333;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: 0.5s ease-in;
}

.navbar{
  width: 80%;
  margin-inline: auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1em 0;

  .logo{
    font-size: 3rem;
  }

  .nav-toggle{
    display: none;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: none;
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 2rem;
  }

  .nav-links ul{
    display: flex;
    gap: 2em;

    li{
      font-size: 1.5rem;

      a{
        color: #fff;
      }
    }
  }

  @media screen and (max-width: 768px){
    .nav-links ul{
      display: none;
    }

    .nav-links.show ul{
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      width: 100%;
      height: 90vh;
      position: absolute;
      top: 90px;
      left: 0;
      background-color: antiquewhite;
      transition: 1s ease-in-out;
      a{
        color: red;
        font-size: 2rem;
      }
    }

    .nav-toggle{
      display: block;
    }

  }
}//end of navbar
```

I have tried to debug it and I have noticed something:

```
.nav-links.show ul{
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      width: 100%;
      height: 90vh;
      position: absolute;
      top: 90px;
      left: 0;
      background-color: antiquewhite;
      transition: 4s ease-in-out;

      a{
        color: red;
        font-size: 2rem;
      }
    }
```

If I change the top: 90px to top: 100% while monitoring the changes, the transitions seems to work. Undoing it again back to top: 90px seems to do nothing. So I thought, maybe adding: top: -100% on .nav-links ul will do the trick but unfortunately still no. So I tried to debug again and noticed that given the addition top: -100%, if I try to remove top: 90px-> save it, then add it again, the transition work. I'm confused, what do I have to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Transitions on `display` property don't work in CSS. In order to achieve the similar result, use the `opacity` property and set `height` to zero instead.

For example:

```scss
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  list-style-type: none;
  text-decoration: none ;
}.wrapper{
  width: 100%;
  height: 90px;
  background: #333;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: 0.5s ease-in;
}

.navbar{
  width: 80%;
  margin-inline: auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1em 0;

  .logo{
    font-size: 3rem;
  }

  .nav-toggle{
    display: none;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: none;
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 2rem;
  }

  .nav-links ul{
    display: flex;
    gap: 2em;

    li{
      font-size: 1.5rem;

      a{
        color: #fff;
      }
    }
  }

  @media screen and (max-width: 768px){
    .nav-links ul{
      // set height and opacity to zero
      height: 0;
      // to prevent overflowing
      overflow: hidden;
      opacity: 0;
    }

    .nav-links.show ul{
      // set height and opacity back
      height: auto;
      opacity: 1;
      flex-direction: column;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      width: 100%;
      height: 90vh;
      position: absolute;
      top: 90px;
      left: 0;
      background-color: antiquewhite;
      transition: 1s ease-in-out;
      a{
        color: red;
        font-size: 2rem;
      }
    }

    .nav-toggle{
      display: block;
    }

  }
}//end of navbar
```

Learn more: [Transitions on the CSS display property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3331353/transitions-on-the-css-display-property).

Comment: Hello, I see, thank you for the information. I didn't know that. Just one follow up question. I followed your advice and it did work, the only problem is that when the hamburger menu is not opened, the icon seems to go far right as shown in the image. 

https://imgur.com/a/pZLVYde

Is there a way to make it even just like the X?

Comment: @MeL17 Try adding `display: inline` on `.nav-links ul` or set width to zero too?